# Matrices Invertibility Existence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I have two square matrices, $A$ and $B$, and I know that $AB = I_n$, how do I then show that $A$ is invertible?

I've been considering determinants, and I have started off by assuming that $A$ is not invertible, and so $det(A) = 0$, and have been trying to find a contradiction, but I'm not getting anywhere, thanks.

Comment: Are you working with matrices over a ring? The question become actually more interesting for matrices over a semiring...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint I assume this are $n\times n$ matrices. $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)=det(I_n)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the determinants of the 2 matrices as you've said above and reach a contradiction.

Assume $A$ and $B$ either have determinant $0$. Using the fact that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ then $AB$ also has determinant $0$.

However, $I_n$ has a determinant of $1$. #

Comment: No, it does not as it doesn't state that $BA = I_n$.

Comment: My apologies for the earlier misunderstanding - I've fixed it.